# How to save a global reference of an instantiated gameobject?

Tags: unity, c#, design-patterns

In my game, when I instantiate a particular prefab, I need to show a GUI window, then let player do some actions, finally close that window and update the caller `GameObject` with the info inserted from user.

So my question is: how to save the reference of the `GameObject` caller to update it at the end of the user action.

Consider that I call some sub functions and I don't want to pass a `GameObject` through all functions.

Is there a way to save a gameObject reference in a global variable ? I'm using a static class for that purpose.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

C# doesn't allow global variables (i.e.: variables outside classes).

The only way to mimic a global variable is to use a `static` class, as you already did.

Answer (score 0):

What's wrong with passing a `GameObject` reference through these functions?

You need it at the end and the only place you can get it is the previous invoker in your chain of methods. When you instantiate the UI, pass the `GameObject` to it, store it in the UI handler class, and when do, do the update thing you need to on that saved reference.